# PHP : Setting first element active with do/while loop

Tags: php, for-loop

Here is my code snippet:

```
for($x=0;$x<=$flaga1;$x++){ 
$index++;
echo "<div class=\"item\" data-slide-number=".$index.">".$sth."</div>"; 
}
```

It iterates the code depending on `$sth`. But I want to add `active` class to the first occurence of the code, so it will be:

```
<div class="active item" data-slide-number="0">"sth"</div>
<div class="item" data-slide-number="1">"sth"</div>
<div class="item" data-slide-number="2">"sth"</div>
```

I'm trying to do something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
for($x=0;$x<=$flaga1;$x++){ 

$active=0;
$divclass="<div class=\"item\"";

do {
    $divclass="<div class=\"active item\"";
    $active++;
} while ($active<=0);


$index++;
echo "".$divclass." data-slide-number=".$index.">".$sth."</div>"; 

}
```

Comment: `echo "<div class=\"item"; if( $x == 0) echo " active"; echo "\" data......`

Comment: Thank you, Niet :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per code submitted by you. You can try this.

```
for($x=0;$x<=$flaga1;$x++){ 
    $active = "";
    if($x === 0 ) {
        $active = "active";
    }
    $index++;
    echo "<div class=\"item\ <?php echo $active; ?>" data-slide-number=".$index.">".$sth."</div>"; 
}
```

Or you can do this, as suggested by  Niet the Dark Absol.

```
for($x=0;$x<=$flaga1;$x++){ 
   $index++;
   echo "<div class=\"item\ <?php if($x === 0) {echo "active"; } ?>" data-slide-number=".$index.">".$sth."</div>"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also set this up in your for loop definition if you like:

```
for ($x = 0, $a = 'active'; $x < $flaga1; $x++, $a = '') {
    echo "<div class=\"item $a\" data-slide-number=". ++$index .">" . $sth . "</div>\n";
}
```